# Converting string to byte array and adding values in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

The input string would look similar to: S214FE0420FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00

I would like to the remove the first 2 digits and the last two digits.
Then I would like to sum the remaining digits in pairs (bytes in hex).
For example: 14+FE+04+20+FF+...

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your: to write a script. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! Stack Overflow is not a free code/script writing service, so you need to try it on your own, and when stuck, come back here and ask a specific question!

Comment: I didn't ask anyone to write any code. I was looking for the most efficient algorithm to use. I don't know what batch scripting has to offer so that's the help I'm looking for.

Comment: But thank you to the people who contributed their time providing solutions.

Comment: It would be prudent to 'mark as answer' any solution which you deem worthy of such.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any own efforts, I decided to provide a simple script; please try something on your own next time!

So here is the code (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_STRING=S214FE0420FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00"
if not defined _STRING set /P _STRING="" & rem // (prompt if empty constant)
set "_TRUNCL=2" & rem // (truncate this many characters from the left)
set "_TRUNCR=2" & rem // (truncate this many characters from the right)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Truncate defined number of characters:
set "STRING=!_STRING:~%_TRUNCL%,-%_TRUNCR%!"
rem // Initialise pointer and buffer:
set /A "POINTER=0, BUFFER=0"
rem // Skip loop if truncated string is empty:
if not defined STRING goto :NEXT
rem // Establish loop to walk through string at every two characters:
:LOOP
rem /* Prefix pointed two characters with `0x` to be interpreted as hexadecimal
rem    number and add them to buffer; afterwards increment pointer by 2 + 1
rem    (the additional 1 is intended to ignore the last digit if there is an
rem    odd number; the 1 is subtracted later again): */
set /A "BUFFER+=0x!STRING:~%POINTER%,2!, POINTER+=3"
rem /* Check if characters are still available at the new pointer, then
rem    subtract the aforementioned 1 from the new pointer: */
if not "!STRING:~%POINTER%!"=="" set /A "POINTER-=1" & goto :LOOP
rem /* No more characters are available, so leave the loop; also subtract the
rem    aforementioned 1 from the new pointer, so it holds the string length: */
set /A "POINTER-=1"
rem // This is the point beyond the loop:
:NEXT
rem // Return the result:
echo/sum:    %BUFFER%
echo/length: %POINTER%
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely unREMarked example, for which I will provide no help.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "input=S214FE0420FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00"
For /L %%A In (2 2 40) Do Set "output=!output!+0x!input:~%%A,2!"
Set/A output=%output:~1%
Echo(%input:~2,-2%=%output%
Timeout -1
```